# user interface design with c++

Tags: c++, user-interface

I want to create a user interface. The format should be example on the following link. I want to use C++ language as PL. So, Do you have any recommendation how can I achieve ?

DEvelopment platform should be both Windows and Linux.

http://www.visualpharm.com/images/Image/Loto%20Master/ui_design_lotomaster_main.png

http://www.crystalxp.net/galerie/img/img-resources-psp-firmware-user-interface-psd-gctonyhawk7-463.jpg

Comment: When asking for recommendations, make your requirements as clear as possible, otherwise there is no way to answer your question other than guessing.

Answer (score 2):

[qt](http://qt.digia.com/Product/)
, 
framework for UI creation in c++. IDE is avaliable for linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

User interface development under Windows and Linux are quite separate fields. On Windows you usually use WinAPI with framework on top (e.g. MFC) while on Linux GTK+ or KDE. However there is a framework which is available for both (Windows and Linux) - [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

Comment: Not only that *Qt* is available on *Windows* and *Linux*, it also beats the *"native"* GUI facilities of *Windows* by orders of magnitude in nearly all aspects.

Comment: two people but same answer